# How to iterate over a directory of files in vimscript?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I have a directory ~/.vim/rc.d/ that houses various configuration files. I like this pattern for configuring various things in my homedir because it modularizes configuration options.

The problem is that my vimrc is now a series of commands to source hard-coded paths to other .vim files.

```
source ~/.vim/rc.d/00-plugins.vim
source ~/.vim/rc.d/01-plugins-settings.vim
source ~/.vim/rc.d/02-interface-colorscheme.vim
source ~/.vim/rc.d/02-interface-listchars.vim
```

Etc.

How can I rewrite this to source all the files in that directory that end in .vim?

Comment: See `:h glob()`, `:h :for`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You may be interested in `:help startup`

Answer (score 4):

You can put all your files to `~/.vim/plugin/` directory and they would be sourced by vim automatically.

Basically vim does `:runtime` all vim files from that directory.

If you still want to do it by hand you can `:runtime! ~/.vim/rc.d/**/*.vim`

You can also use `glob()` function to get all your vim filenames and source them in a for loop.

Comment: Thanks, since I had nothing in `~/.vim/plugin` I removed it and created a symlink to `~/.vim/rc.d` and that seems to be working.

Comment: Actually, this symlinking seems to have broken vim-plug. I did not have success adding the runtime! command to my vimrc either unfortunately :(

Answer (score 3):

The doc [`:h :runtime`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Aruntime) says:

```
:ru[ntime][!] [where] {file} ..
            Read Ex commands from {file} in each directory given
            by 'runtimepath' and/or 'packpath'.  There is no error
            for non-existing files.
            [...]
            When [!] is included, all found files are sourced.
            [...]
            When {file} contains wildcards it is expanded to all
            matching files.  Example: >
                :runtime! plugin/*.vim
```

So you should be able to use `runtime! ~/.vim/rc.d/*`

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to break vim-plug. I'm not sure why